# help? weird bug

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, steganography

hey stackoverflowers im very new to html so if one of you could give me a pointer on what went wrong here that would be really helpful. im trying to make an online⠀order⠀site but something happened and now the whole page appears blank but its just showing `lang="en">`? idk i keep running into bugs and dont know how to deal with ⠀them⠀.

anyways, heres a link to the site if you could tell me whats wrong thank you! https://thesanitorium.neocities.org

---

yes this is a puzzle, done on a very small scale and shoddily put together in an hour but i think itll keep you thinking for a short while. enjoy :D

Comment: Puzzles posted on this site should be self-contained. This post is a link to a treasure hunt style puzzle hosted elsewhere (most likely because the Stack Exchange site format doesn't have the necessary functionality), so if the link ever stops working, the post will become useless.

Comment: I get the reasoning @Bass and don't disagree with the rule. 

It's just a shame because these types of puzzles are a personal favorite and there's no other way to post those here.

Comment: @Bass ah sorry, i was unaware, ill refrain from doing puzzles like this in the future.

Comment: Someone who's made such a puzzle can post a link to it in the "Sphinx's Lair" site chatroom. Of course you don't get the Meaningless Internet Points for doing that, but it's a way to direct some attention to your puzzle and I don't think anyone would object to it (unless e.g. the thing is boring and plastered with advertisements).